# php mysql compare two columns return mismatches

Tags: php, sql, mysql, compare

I have two columns in different product tables.

`tblproduct1.partno` is an old product list

`tblproduct2.partno2` is a new one

Both `partno` columns should have identical model numbers but they don't.

When executing the below query, I get about 300 model numbers that don't match when comparing counts from both tables. `tblproduct2` has 1955 records, the query below is 1638. I would expect it to return 1955.

```
SELECT COUNT(partno)
FROM tblproduct1
  INNER JOIN tblproduct2 ON partno = partno2
```

Is there a way I can list the model numbers that don't match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually stereofrogs query is correct. It works even when the table columns are defined as 'not null'  I suspect you had the two tables mixed up when you ran the query.

that is because the *LEFT JOIN always has all the rows from the left table in it*. If the second table does not have a matching entry it will be displayed as NULL.

So as long as you have the table with more rows as the left (or the first) table the above query will produce the desired result.

Comment: Yes it works, thanks for the explanation, how do I list the models in the null column? I need to compare them

Comment: you can add a second column to the query so that you have something to compare against eg: select tblproduct1.partno, tblproduct.partName ...

all the best

Answer (score 2):

```
select tblproduct1.partno from tblproduct1
   left join tblproduct2 on tblproduct1.partno = tblproduct2.partno2
   where tblproduct2.partno2 is null
```

shows tblproduct1.partno that have no matching tblproduct2.partno2 values

Comment: the partno2 isn't null, it just doesn't match

Comment: sorry, I can see the query works thanks for the answer, i have asked  e4c5, but I'll reinstate the question here: is there a way to see the model number?  tblproduct2.partno2  returns null